# How can I check whether a particular document ID contains a certain value inside it?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

first I want to check whether a particular document ID exists or not using the `.exist` method. If exists, then I want to check whether that document id `containsValue == true` else do some other stuff.

Currently, I am using a `FutureBuilder` to get the details from Firebase, but it's not working perfectly.

I have attached an image of the database where it contains a document ID with +91919982779295 and a field name "verified" which is set to true. Just want to check whether the document ID exists, if exist then it contains the value true as shown in the comment section of the code.

I guess it will be done by `.exist` and `.containsValue` method but I don't know how to put them together inside `FutureBuilder`

**Here is my code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class Navigatorpage extends StatefulWidget {

  var phoneNumber;

  Navigatorpage({this.phoneNumber});

  @override
  _NavigatorpageState createState() => _NavigatorpageState();
}

class _NavigatorpageState extends State<Navigatorpage> {

  var phoneNumber;
  final Firestore firestore = Firestore.instance;

  _NavigatorpageState({this.phoneNumber});


  Future<DocumentSnapshot> getDetails() =>firestore.collection('users').document(+919982779295).get();



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: FutureBuilder(
        future: Future.wait([
          getDetails()
        ]),
        builder: (context, snapshot){
          Here first need to check



              if( the documentId named +919982779295 exists){
                 if( if exits then check whether it contains the value true as show in the image using  
          containsValue method)
                   { return something;}
               else { return something;}
                 }
           else {return something;}
          }
          
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out... this is what i was looking for

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:kartofill/Phoneverification.dart';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:kartofill/Splashscreen.dart';

class Navigatorpage extends StatefulWidget {

  var phoneNumber;

  /* Navigatorpage({this.phoneNumber}); */

  @override
  _NavigatorpageState createState() => _NavigatorpageState();
}

class _NavigatorpageState extends State<Navigatorpage> {

  var phoneNumber;
  String font;
  /*final Firestore firestore = Firestore.instance;*/

  /*_NavigatorpageState({this.phoneNumber}); */


  Future <String> getDetails() async{
 final snapShot = await Firestore.instance.collection('users').document('+919954603381').get();
 if(snapShot.exists){
   if(snapShot.data.containsValue("true")){
        font='a';

   }
  else{
     font='b';
   }
 }
 else{
   font='c';
 }

 return font.toString();
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(

      future: Future.wait([getDetails()]),
      builder: (context,snapshot){
        print(snapshot.data.toString());
        switch(snapshot.data.toString()) {

          case'[a]': {

           return Phoneverification();
          }
          break;

          case '[b]': {
            return Text('B');
          }
          break;

          case '[c]': {
            return Text('C');
          }
          break;

          default: {
            return Text('Default');
          }
          break;
        }

      },





    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question, I would like to answer it. 
I think this can do something for you.

```
    var collection = Firestore.instance.collection('collectionName');
    var docID = '+919982779295'
    collection.document(docID).get().then((document) => {
     if(document.exists){
        if(document.data['verified'] == 'true'){
               return 'Verified!';
        }else{
               return 'Not Verified!';
        }
     }else{
        return 'Does Not Exist!'
    }
    });
```

In addition to this, you can catch any Exceptions using .catch() after .then().

Comment: I want to fetch this in a page i mean i donot have a button where i can use onpress function that is easy I just want whenever this page loads the checks in the questions are done... Can i use your code inside a Future builder

Comment: Instead, use a function (returning a widget) that contains this code. Instead of returning some string here, return a widget you want. Finally, call the function and set the state in void initState (); Refer: https://www.bookstack.cn/read/flutterbyexample/aebe8dda4df3319f.md